# Copy files within iCloud drive without downloading them

Tags: ios, icloud-drive

Using FileManager.moveItem I can move a file in iCloud to another location in iCloud without downloading it locally. I would like to perform the same thing but with FileManager.copyItem, in the sense that I would like to make copies of files within iCloud without downloading them locally.

With FileManager.copyItem it seems to not be possible.

Moreover, analysing the .js of icloud.com/iclouddrive I see /moveItems and other endpoints, but no /copyItems. There is however, a "DuplicateItems" string in a "transactionType" array, but I cannot understand how to use it.

Comment: Question: Can you still `FileManager.moveItem` without downloading? Bc, when I try it right now it gives me *"<FILE>" couldn’t be moved to “<App>” because an item with the same name already exists* and using `FileManager.copyItem` gives me * couldn’t be opened because there is no such file* did you find a way to do it?

Comment: @thisIsTheFoxe It is doable, before iCloud items downloaded to your device, iCloud will create a placeholder item in the disk, like ".abc.jpg.icloud" for the file "abc.jpg", if you move this placeholder item using "FileManager.default.moveItem", you are moving the file in iCloud drive without downloading it first.